# Run local GCC on remote linux server

Tags: linux, gcc, ssh, makefile, configure

I'm sure this has been asked before but after some time searching I'm not finding quite what I want.

I have a test server that I cannot install GCC or other development needs on.  On my development linux computer I can ssh to the test server, I want to install certain packages that require running ./configure and make.

Is there a way to run the make processes on my computer pointed at the remote host to install that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with doing this is that your build process needs to see the libraries on your test server. So you probably should do one of these:

- Set up a virtual machine with the same configuration as your test server, and add the development tools to that.
- Install the development tools to a custom location your test server.
- Use OverlayFS to install development tools in a "virtual environment" on the test server.